# Sorting a ListBox in c# with multiple fields

Tags: c#, list, listbox

Is there a way to sort a list box on one field then another?

(I saw the other posts but I think this is a bit more involved).  I could do this the long way but thought there was a faster shorthand version I just wasn't aware of.

Basically this reads a directory for all the folders in it with the format of:

```
DATENAME
```

I parse out the name from the date.  I need to organize these by name THEN by date (the second filter is what is tripping me up).

So a folder of:

```
12012016TULLY
1202019LAVA
2202018LAVA
5162019CLOUD
5202020LAVA
```

would look like

```
5162019CLOUD
2202018LAVA
1202019LAVA
5202020LAVA
12012016TULLY
```

So this is what I have:

```
class MyListBoxItem
{
    public string StudyBaseFolder { get; set; }
    public string StudyName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string StudyDate { get; set; }
}

List<MyListBoxItem> studiesAndFolders = new List<MyListBoxItem>();

//later int he code i build a list of studyNames (which is a path and I pasre the path here too)
foreach (string sn in studyName)
{
    //get user name

    String lastName = getLastName(sn);
    String theDate = getDate(sn);

    //can I organize this based on the LAST NAME THEN THE DATE
    studiesAndFolders.Add(new MyListBoxItem { StudyBaseFolder = path, StudyName = sn, UserLastName = lastName, StudyDate = theDate }); 

 }
```

Then I finally add this to the listbox.

```
listDirectories.Items.Clear();

//I do it this way so a double click on an item gets the object back and I can do things with it. 
foreach(MyListBoxItem direc in studiesAndFolders)
{
    listDirectories.Items.Add(direc);
}
```

`listbox.sorted=true` didn't help, and I am sure there might be an expression (LINQ to the rescue?).  I was just going to do it the long way with a ton of cases when I take the `studiesAndFolders` and put it to the list.

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: @Freggar visual studio and the standards windows UI (forget what it's called.  Windows forms?  Desktop app)

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ?

Comment: Why not simply do the sort before you add to the `ListBox`?

Answer (score 0):

This code sorts by name, then by date.  And should be easy to read.

```
foreach(MyListBoxItem direc in studiesAndFolders.OrderBy(x => x.StudyName).ThenBy(x => x.StudyDate))
{
    listDirectories.Items.Add(direc);
}
```

As others have noted, you should be storing the `StudyDate` as a `DateTime` unless you want it sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change type of `StudyDate` to `DateTime`

```
class MyListBoxItem
{
    ...
    public DateTime StudyDate { get; set; }
}
```

After, create new comparer

```
public class MyListBoxItemComparer : IComparer<MyListBoxItem>
{
    public int Compare(MyListBoxItem x, MyListBoxItem y)
    {
        if (x.StudyName == y.StudyName)
        {
            return x.StudyDate.CompareTo(y.StudyDate);
        }

        return String.Compare(x.StudyName, y.StudyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

Finally, use `SortedSet` instead of `List`

```
SortedSet<MyListBoxItem> studiesAndFolders = new SortedSet<MyListBoxItem>(new MyListBoxItemComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

For ordering based on the date correctly you need `StudyDate` to be of type `DateTime`

```
class MyListBoxItem
{
    public string StudyBaseFolder { get; set; }
    public string StudyName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StudyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can order by using LINQ extension methods.

```
var orderedDirectories = 
    directories.OrderBy(dir => dir.StudyName)
               .ThenBy(dir => dir.StudyDate);

foreach (var directory in orderedDirectories)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(directory);
}
```

You can override `.ToString()` method in `MyListBoxItem` class that listbox will display items as you want.

```
class MyListBoxItem
{
    public string StudyBaseFolder { get; set; }
    public string StudyName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StudyDate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{StudyDate:MMddyyyy}{StudyName}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `ThenBy` not `Then`

Comment: @Zer0, thanks fixed. We definitely need intellisense here ;)

Comment: Ha, I wish.  Also think you mean type `DateTime` not `Date` as well.

Comment: so i tested each one of these ways of doing things with the above directory structure and it doesn't seem to be organizing it at all.   The list box gets it in the same order as it comes in as.  I get no errors in the code when I execute.  Even if the dates weren't being parsed right (I am using `                DateTime.TryParseExact(theDate, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
`   The names should still and yet they aren't.  *scratches head*

Answer (score -1):

If you can use LINQ in your project, first you should make StudyDate type of DateTime. Then you could do this:

`MyList.OrderBy(x => x.StudyName).ThenByDescending(x=>x.StudyDate).ToList()`